# MySQL table order by one column when other column has a particular value

Tags: mysql, hql

I have two mysql tables ***record_items***,***property_values*** with the following structure.

```
table : property_values (column REC is foreign key to record_items)

id(PK)|REC(FK)| property | value|
 1    | 1     | name     |   A  |
 2    | 1     | age      |   10 |
 3    | 2     | name     |   B  |
 4    | 3     | name     |   C  |
 5    | 3     | age      |   9  |

table: record_items

id(PK) |col1|col2 |col3| 
1      | v11| v12 | v13|
2      | v21| v22 | v23|
3      | v31| v32 | v33|
4      | v41| v42 | v43|
5      | v51| v52 | v53|
```

record_items table contains only basic information about the record, where as property_values table keeps record_item as a foreign key and each property and its value is saved in a separate row.

Now I want to get the record_items sorted based on a particular property,  say by age.
My HQL query will be like

```
Select distinct rec from PropertyValues where property="age" order by value;
```

But this query will be skipping record 2 since it don't have an entry for property age. 
I expect the result to have the records which contains age property in sort order appended by those which don't have age property at all. How can I query that?

Comment: How can we relate age in the `record_items` table?  Your data doesn't look normalized to me.

Comment: i just gave an example. Record_items can have huge number of properties say around 1000 and that is dynamic like all the records won't be having values for all the columns. So instead of keeping 1000 columns in record_items table I am maintaining only few basic columns in record_items  table and a separate table property_values  stores each property and value for record items. (age column I gave as a example)

Comment: OK...what behavior do you want if a given record in `record_items` does not map to a property?  How should it be ordered?

Comment: I want to get the record_items which are mapped to that property in sorted order appended with the record_items which are not mapped (Assuming for every entry in record_item there will be at least one entry in property_values table. Any record item will have at least one property)

Comment: I'm not sure if you miss-typed it on SO but you have **property_values** in table example but **propertyValues** in query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a raw MySQL query which should do the trick:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM record_items t1
LEFT JOIN property_values t2
    ON t1.id = t2.REC AND
       t2.property = 'age'
ORDER BY CASE WHEN t2.value IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, t2.Value
```

I notice that your `Value` column in `property_values` is mixing numeric and text data.  This won't work well for sorting purposes.

## Demo here

Comment: That works thanks :) . Just for clarification ,what if I use Select distinct rec from PropertyValues where (property="age"  or property="name") order by value; assuming name property will be there for all records? Will it work the same way always?

Comment: Your current query seems far from what is needed to answer your question.  If you have a second question, then clarify your original post and maybe it can be answered.

Comment: Can you please give me HQL query for the same ? When I give ON clause I am getting unexpected token ON and if I don't give Path expected for join error I am getting

Comment: Answering this in HQL would require knowing what your entities are, etc.  You should open a new question for the HSQL part in my opinion.  You can reference this question there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43864333/path-expected-for-join-error-in-hibernate-left-join

Comment: can u help me with this?

Comment: I don't know if HQL supports ordering by a `CASE` expression.  But this isn't the place to ask, use your other question.