# Path expected for join Error in Hibernate LEFT JOIN

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Hibernate query for [this mysql query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43862718/3778710)  is giving me following errors

```
FROM RecordItems t1
LEFT JOIN PropertyValues t2 where t2.property = 'age'ORDER BY CASE WHEN t2.value IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, t2.value
```

> Exception : Path expected for join!

```
 FROM RecordItems t1
    LEFT JOIN PropertyValues t2 ON t1.id = t2.REC where t2.property = 'age'ORDER BY CASE WHEN t2.value IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, t2.value
```

> Exception : unexpected token: ON near line 1

Hibernate mappings and entity details are provided below :

```
public class RecordItems implements java.io.Serializable {
     private Integer id;
     private String col1;
     private String col2;
     private String col3;
}
public class PropertyValues implements java.io.Serializable {
     private Integer id;
     private RecordItems REC;
     private String property;
     private String value;

}

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema package="com.test.p.schema" name="Core Package">
<Class name="RecordItems"table="record_items">
        <id name="id" type="integer"column="ID" ><generator class="native" /></id>
        <property name="col1" type="String"  column="col1" />
        <property name="col2" type="String"  column="col2" />
        <property name="col3" type="String"  column="col3" />

    </Class>
<Class name="PropertyValues "table="property_values">
        <id name="id" type="integer"column="ID" ><generator class="native" /></id>
        <foreign cardinality="many"name="REC" class="RecordItems" column="REC" />
        <property name="property" type="String"  column="property" />
        <property name="value" type="String"  column="value" />

    </Class>
</schema>
```

Comment: HQL works on object structure, not on table structure it must be something like : FROM RecordItems t1
LEFT JOIN t1.<property>. But it is hard to say without knowing your entities

Comment: My Hibernate Objects use the same names as table column names. I will provide Object details in description

Comment: Even if I don't give the where and order clause I am getting this error FROM RecordItems t1
    LEFT JOIN PropertyValues t2 ON t1.id = t2.REC

Comment: read my comment exactly `LEFT JOIN t1.<property>. `

Comment: Where is the hibernate mapping for your objects?

Comment: I have defined the Objects, u want me to provide the xml mappings as well ?

Comment: Yes that is needed

Comment: @Jens added that